# Is it correct to use `Future` to run some loop task which is never finished?

Tags: scala, future

In our project, we need to do a task which listens to a queue and process the coming messages in a loop, which is never finished. The code is looking like:

```
def processQueue = {
  while(true) {
    val message = queue.next();
    processMessage(message) match {
      case Success(_) => ...
      case _ => ...
    }
  }
}
```

So we want to run it in a separate thread.

I can imagine two ways to do it, one is to use `Thread` as what we do in Java:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() { processQueue() }).start();
```

Another way is use `Future` (as we did now):

```
Future { processQueue }
```

I just wonder if is it correct to use `Future` in this case, since as I know(which might be wrong), `Future` is mean to be running some task which will finish or return a result in some time of the future. But our task is never finished.

I also wonder what's the best solution for this in scala.

Comment: Future is a deferred computation, not a Thread doing its own job. There are different Future implementations possible - your use case may (due to non-termination) break the system depending on the underlying impl (e.g. single threaded execution context in the Scala's impl). You might use a thread or a dedicated single threaded executor service for this.

Answer (score 5):

A `Future` is supposed to a value that will eventually exist, so I don't think it makes much sense to create one that will never be fulfilled. They're also immutable, so passing information to them is a no-no. And using some externally referenced queue within the `Future` sounds like dark road to go down.

What you're describing is basically an Akka `Actor`, which has it's own FIFO queue, with a `receive` method to process messages. It would look something like this:

```
import akka.actor._

class Processor extends Actor {
    def receive = {
        case msg: String => processMessage(msg) match {
            case Success(x) => ...
            case _ => ...
        }
        case otherMsg @ Message(_, _) => {
            // process this other type of message..
        }
    }
}
```

Your application could create a single instance of this `Processor` actor with an `ActorSystem` (or some other elaborate group of these actors):

```
val akkaSystem = ActorSystem("myActorSystem")
val processor: ActorRef = akkaSystem.actorOf(Props[Processor], "Processor")
```

And send it messages:

```
processor ! "Do some work!"
```

In short, it's a better idea to use a concurrency framework like Akka than to create your own for processing queues on separate threads. The `Future` API is most definitely not the way to go.

I suggest perusing the [Akka Documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala.html) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

If you are just running one thread (aside from the main thread), it won't matter.  If you do this repeatedly, and you really want lots of separate threads, you should use `Thread` since that is what it is for.  Futures are built with the assumption that they'll terminate, so you might run out of pool threads.